# This prolog query should return true instead it returns a list

Tags: prolog

I am writing the follwing prolog program

```
pair([],X,[]).
pair([L1], X, [L2]) :- L2 = (L1,X).
pair([H1|L1], X, [H2|L2]) :- pair(L1,X,L2), H2 = (H1,X).
```

it returns true for this:

```
pair([1,2,3],a,[(1,a),(2,a),(3,a)]).
```

and the following:

```
listOfPairs([]):-[].
listOfPairs([(X,Y)|L]) :- H=(X,Y), listOfPairs(L).
```

which returns true if the elements in the list are pair.

now I have :

```
pair([a,1,d], 2, L), listOfPairs(L).
```

which is suppose to return true, since  `L = [ (a, 2), (1, 2), (d, 2)]` 
and  the list of pairs returns true, however this one returns the L only. I have used trace to see why doesnt work, but it really didnt help me.

Comment: `listOfPairs([]) :- [].` isn't valid. You probably meant `listOfPairs([]).`. I'm not sure what you mean by, *...this one returns the L only*. When I run your code without the "fix" I mention, I get an error. If I fix it, then it works.

Comment: still the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, the following clause needs to be fixed:

```
listOfPairs([]):-[].
```

It will fail in GNU Prolog because `[]/0` isn't an existing predicate. You can change it to:

```
listOfPairs([]).
```

Next, if you call:

```
pair([a,1,d], 2, L), listOfPairs(L).
```

You will get (in GNU Prolog):

```
L = [(a,2),(1,2),(d,2)] ? a

L = [(a,2),(1,2),(d,2)]

(1 ms) yes
```

This means that `pair` succeeded with a value of `L` shown. `listOfPairs` succeeded as well and the entire clause succeeds (thus the `yes`).

If you don't want to see the intermediate values of `L`, you need another predicate:

```
myCheck(X, Y) :-
    pair(X, Y, L),
    listOfPairs(L).
```

Then you get:

```
| ?- myCheck([a,1,d], 2).

true ? a

yes
```

You should see something similar in SWI Prolog (you didn't mention which interpreter you are using).